# <<Fluent python>> P372 example 8-19 why only exist last element?

Tags: python

```
import weakref

class Cheese:
  def __init__(self,kind):
    self.kind = kind

  def __repr__(self):
    return "cheese {}".format(self.kind)



stock = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
catalog = [Cheese("red"),Cheese("block"),Cheese("lock"),Cheese("hehe")]
for cheese in  catalog:
    stock[cheese.kind] = cheese

print(sorted(stock.keys()))
del catalog
print(sorted(stock.keys()))
```

result is :

```
['block', 'hehe', 'lock', 'red']
['hehe']
```

Question: why result is not :

```
['block', 'hehe', 'lock', 'red']
['block', 'hehe', 'lock', 'red']
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're using a `weakref.WeakValueDictionary()` for `stock`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html):

> A weak reference to an object is not enough to keep the object alive: when the only remaining references to a referent are weak references, **garbage collection is free to destroy the referent and reuse its memory for something else**.

So destroying `catalog` allows the garbage collector to destroy `stock` contents.

Only remaining element is the last one because it's referenced by the last loop item as `cheese`

If you perform a `del cheese`, then the second printout is completely empty.

Answer (score 2):

A `WeakValueDictionary` will dispose the items if the values are not referenced anywhere else anymore.

In your case all values are referenced in `catalog`, and one item additionally as `cheese` (left over from the last iteration). When `catalog` is deleted only one element has an other reference, the others get disposed.